# display recent uploaded image in php only display single image corresponding to the ther data submited to that fie

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

I want to display uploaded image to a different page showing first name last name and image corresponding to that upload this is the code I have it currently displaying all the images save on a folder I just want to display the recent uploaded image corresponding to the information submitted

```
  <?php 

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pa…
 if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
  mysql_select_db("database", $con);




   $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (fname, lname, mname, image, status, id)



           VALUES
        ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[mname]','$_PO… 'display','')";
       if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
                 {
             die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                     echo "";
                mysql_close($con);
                  ?>               <?php
            // Assigning value about your server to variables for database connection
        $hostname_connect= "localhost";
            $database_connect= "database";
                  $username_connect= "username";
            $password_connect= "password";
   $connect_solning = mysql_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or      trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR… 
    @mysql_select_db($database_connect) or die (mysql_error()); 
    if($_POST)
     { 
    // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name              of input field you have in form tag.



                     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
           {
        // if there is error in file uploading 
               echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "
                ";



         }
           else
              {
          // check if file already exit in "images" folder.
            if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
   else
       { //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image. 
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["t… . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
      // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
       $query_image = "insert into table";

     if(mysql_query($query_image))
      {
         echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
           }
           else
      {
        echo'';
    }
   }
          }




        }
           }
         ?>
        <html>
     <head>
             </head>
          <body>
           <p>First name: <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?><br></p>
             <p>Middle name: <?php echo $_POST["mname"]; ?><br></p>
                <p>Last name: <?php echo $_POST["lname"]; ?><br></p>


          </form>
         </body>
                </html> 

                <?php
       // Assigning value about your server to variables for database connection
         $hostname_connect= "localhost";
               $database_connect= "database";
                $username_connect= "username";
               $password_connect= "password";
    $connect_solning = mysql_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or           trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR… 
  @mysql_select_db($database_connect) or die (mysql_error()); 

             $query_image = "SELECT * FROM table";
           // This query will show you all images if you want to see only one image pass            id='$id' e.g. "SELECT * FROM nametable id='$id'".
    $result = mysql_query($query_image);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
         {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo '<img width="165" height="104" border="0" src="images/'.$row["image"].'">';

              }
         }
              else
          {
             echo 'File name not found in database';
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: never eat the POST or GET contents raw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query_image = "SELECT * FROM table order by id desc limit 1";
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what this does and why it works.